# Как сделать так, чтобы ballon в vue yandex map открывался при открытии компонента

Tags: vue.js, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Всем привет, я хочу сделать так, что бы balloon открывался сразу при открытии компонента, но у меня не получилось сделать и на данный момент он открывается только кликом на маркер.

```
<template>
  <div class="default-modal map-modal">
    <div class="default-modal__body map-modal__body">
      <button class="btn map-modal__close" @click="$emit('close')">Закрыть</button>
      <div class="map-modal__map">
        <ClientOnly v-if="mapReady">
          <yandex-map ref="map" :settings="settings" :coords="coords" zoom="14" :controls="['zoomControl']">
            <ymap-marker :icon="icon" :coords="coords" :properties="properties" marker-id="123" />
          </yandex-map>
        </ClientOnly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { loadYmap, yandexMap, ymapMarker } from "vue-yandex-maps";
import ClientOnly from "vue-client-only";

export default {
  name: "MapModal",
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      mapReady: false,
      debounceInterval: null,
      coords: [42.89049523595949, 47.63682007602924],
      marker: null,
      map: null,
      settings: {
        apiKey: "",
        lang: "ru_RU",
        coordorder: "latlong",
        version: "2.1",
      },
      icon: {
        layout: "default#image",
        imageHref: "/static/images/map-red-location.png",
        imageSize: [40, 56],
        imageOffset: [-18, -56],
        balloonImageSize: [0, 0],
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    properties() {
      return {
        balloonContentHeader: "Курьерский адрес",
        balloonContentBody: this.data.address,
      };
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initMap();
    this.debounceInterval = setInterval(() => {
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        this.mapReady = false;
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.initMap();
        });
      });
    }, 500);
  },
  methods: {
    initMap() {
      loadYmap(this.settings).then(() => {
        window.ymaps.ready(() => {
          window.ymaps.geocode(this.data.address).then((res) => {
            this.coords = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
            this.mapReady = true;
          });
        });
      });
    },
  },
  components: { yandexMap, ymapMarker, ClientOnly },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var balloon = this.map.balloon;
balloon.setData(this.properties);
balloon.open(this.map.getCenter());
```